# Minimize or find a n ideal subset-sums from a list of numbers which are less than or equal to some N

Tags: python, c++, dynamic, tree, subset-sum

Given a list of numbers, `lst = [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1]` how would I find an ideal number of lists which are less than or equal to 4?

There are many possibilities here. The goal is to minimize the number of possible lists. The program would need to do create subset lists like the following: `{4}, {4}, {3, 1}, ... , {1, 1}`.

Notice how the last list subset does not equal to four, but it less. This problem is difficult for the following reasons:

- The program must be able to find `subset-sums` which are less than or equal to a sum
- The program will needs to *begin* by removing values out of the original list into subset lists by first looking at the **largest** values

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For now I have just thought it up. My education is Engineering, so I was hoping to come across a CS on here who knows a bit more about graph theory, or something.

Comment: The subset contains two elements at max? Is `{1,1,1}` one of the possible outcomes?

Comment: `{1, 1, 1}` is a possible outcome, yes. I did not know a subset contains a maximum of two elements.

Comment: @GeneralCode Didn't mean to take a dig at you. My algorithm doesn't have {1,1} in the solutions, hence asked. Could you post some sample input and output if you have to validate the algo?

Comment: @Wander3r, I have thought about a solution. I will code it tomorrow, it is recursion. The solution: reorder the list from largest to smallest, remove, go through remainder of list recursively to find values that sum to less than equal to N. If you think up a solution which is not recursion, I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt.
The general idea is to sort the list, and go from left and right and picking the biggest subset every iteration greedily. The time complexity is `O(n)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lst{1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1};
    std::sort(lst.begin(),lst.end()); //sort the list
    int target = 4;

    int left = 0;
    int right = lst.size()-1;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> solutions;
    while (left<right ){
        if(lst[left] > target)   // break if no solutions
            break;

        if(lst[right] > target) // ignore larger right values
            right--;


        if(lst[right]<=target){   // while the total sum is less than target, keep adding the elements
            std::vector<int> subset;
            subset.push_back(lst[right]);
            int sum = lst[right];
            while(left<right && lst[left]+sum<=target){
                sum+=lst[left];
                subset.push_back({lst[left]});
                left++;
            }
            solutions.push_back(subset);
            right--;
        }

    }

    for(auto& ss : solutions){
        std::cout<<'{';
        for(auto n:ss){
            std::cout<<n<<',';
        }
        std::cout<<"\b}";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm impressed with how fast you came up with that, thank you for the help.